# How can I get browsers to download an exe instead of opening it in the browser window?

Tags: html, download, exe

I have a website from which I want to enable browser users to download an exe.

I am testing it with a very simple HTML file which I load into the web browser with "File>Open". The "body" looks something like this:

```
<body>
<a href="http://www.example.com/myprogram.exe" target="_self">click to download exe</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/myprogram.zip" target="_self">click to download zip</a>
</body>
```

The issue is this: when I click on the first link (myprogram.exe), the browser (IE8 as well as FireFox) streams the myprogram.exe directly into the browser window: I see a whole lot of binary.

When I click on the second link (myprogram.zip), the browser asks me if I would like to open the file or save it to disk, which is what I expected to happen with the .exe.

This is the ONLY .exe download that causes this strange behaviour.  I have downloaded .exes often and the browsers always ask me whether to open the file or save to disk.

Is there something that needs to be set on the web site itself, or the host or ... ?

Comment: If you open (file>open) the html document from the file system (i.e. using the file protocol) you by definition do NOT have a website as you say.

Comment: Well, not quite true:  you're correct in seeing that my test html document is not hosted on the web site, but the file that I'm trying to download is on the web site.

Comment: If the browser is supposed to download the file, why do you have the target element set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct the content-type your webserver is sending. It sounds like it is claiming that the data is `text/plain`. My mime.types file suggests exe files should be `application/x-msdos-program`

If you are using Apache, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype (or the similar page in the manual for the version you are using).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [`Content-Disposition` HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1).

UPDATE: The HTTP headers are typically controlled in the web server, e.g., Apache.

As another poster mentions, most browsers should download `.exe` files as an attachment automatically if the server is sending the correct [`Content-Type` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17). How to do this varies from server to server. Here's an article on [setting MIME types (another name for content-type) in IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742440.aspx). In Apache, it is typically done by editing the file your [`TypesConfig` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod%5Fmime.html#typesconfig) points to.

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer. I'm sorry to be dim, but how do I do that in my HTML page?

Comment: You have to configure your webserver to send out the correct headers associated with the `.exe`-extension. How to do this, depends on your webserver.

Comment: You shouldn't need to set the content-disposition header, browsers should Do The Right Thing for executables if the correct content-type is set.

Comment: I agree, David.  Of all file types that should NOT be opened in a browser window, I should imagine that .exe would come pretty close to the top of the list.  Why are they happy to treat .zip in the expected manner, but not .exe.  Maybe there's a good answer out there? ...

Comment: Hi Peter. Have you checked the headers that your server is sending? You can probably see these by using `curl -i $uri_for_your_exe` If it's not sending the proper `Content-Type` and/or `Content-Disposition` headers, you need to do some server configuration.

Comment: Thanks, Hank.  It's a bit of a long story, but I'm not the web site author, it's a colleague of mine who is doing that, and I'm just trying to help him trouble shoot this one issue.  I'll pass on your advice, though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the end it required
    AddType application/x-octet-stream exe
being applied.

Thanks to all the answerers who pointed me that way.

Answer (score 0):

See this

[How To Raise a "File Download" Dialog Box for a Known MIME Type](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519)

When you serve a document from a Web server, you might want to immediately prompt the user to save the file directly to the user's disk, without opening it in the browser. However, for known MIME (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions) types such as Microsoft Word ("application/ms-word"), the default behavior is to open the document in Internet Explorer.

You can use the content-disposition header to override this default behavior. Its format is:

> Content-disposition: attachment;
>   filename=fname.ext