# Why I can't make an exe file downloable? HTML - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, download

I have a file `.exe` on apache server into a folder and I try to download it using simple html and javascript but it is not working, I'm trying with this methods

`<a href="folder/myfile.exe" target="_blank">Download</a>`

Even with javascript

`window.location = "folder/myfile.exe";`

I tried with differents files including images, .txt, etc and it works well, the problem is with `.exe` is just show a blank page or keep loading, there is a specific way to make `.exe` downloable?, I'm using Chrome

Comment: if you rename it to zip, does it still download?

Comment: @TankorSmash yes, it works well with .zip or .rar but I need to use .exe

Comment: You'd think that for security reasons, browsers may block the download of .exe files. Yes I remain wondering, how come I can download .exe files from some websites ? Maybe it requires HTTPS... have you taken a look at this SO question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502960/how-can-i-get-browsers-to-download-an-exe-instead-of-opening-it-in-the-browser-w ?

Comment: Have you tried other browsers then? That would help narrow down if it is a server or a browser issue.

Comment: Do you have any antivirus software or browser extensions running?

Comment: @j08691 antivirus maybe on the server but I'm not really sure

Comment: @mherzig yes I tried with firefox and internet explorer but was the same problem